# Error creating function with array return type

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-errors, return

Why is there an error when I tried to build a function with array return type in Java:

```
private int[] swap(int[] nums, i, j){
        int temp=nums[i];
        nums[i]=nums[j];
        nums[j]=temp;
        return nums;
    }
```

I wanna define this function in a class, but there is a compile error:

```
error: <identifier> expected
```

I don't know the reason

Answer (score 2):

In the method signature you have:

```
private int[] swap(int[] nums, i, j)
```

However what is `i`? What is `j`? You have to specify what type they are for the compiler. Change it to:

```
private int[] swap(int[] nums, int i, int j)
```

To specify that `i` and `j` are `int`'s

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the types of `i` and `j`:

```
private int[] swap(int[] nums, int i, int j) {
    // Here -------------------^------^
```